# c# bitmap block comparison

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I try to compare small blocks of 100x100 pixels between 2 images.
I use the native `memcmp` pinvoke call after the `LockBits` operation,this is my code:

```
    private void CompareBlock(Bitmap bmp1,Bitmap bmp2)
    {
        Rectangle lockRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
        BitmapData bmData = bmp1.LockBits(lockRect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        BitmapData bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(lockRect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;
        int BytesPerPixel = 4;//images are 32bpprgb
        Size BlockSize = new Size(100,100);
        if (memcmp(scan0, scan02, (BlockSize.Width * BlockSize.Height * BytesPerPixel))==0)//need to compare only the the first 100x100 pixels block.
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Equal");
            //do somthing with the block;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong,but the program actually enters the condition,and prints `"Equal"` which is not true(according to the given images).

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

//code updated test

```
      private void CompareBlock(Bitmap bmp1,Bitmap bmp2)
    {
        Rectangle lockRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
        BitmapData bmData = bmp1.LockBits(lockRect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        BitmapData bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(lockRect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;
        int BytesPerPixel = 4;
        Size BlockSize = new Size(100,100);

        for (int y = 0; y < BlockSize.Height; y++)
        {
            if (memcmp(scan0, scan02, BlockSize.Width * BytesPerPixel) == 0)//need to compare only the the first 100x100 pixels block.
            {
                scan0 = IntPtr.Add(scan0, stride);//not sure about that advancement
                scan02 = IntPtr.Add(scan02, stride2);//not sure about that advancement

                //do somthing with the block;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I recommended [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp) a few days ago to someone who needed to lock bitmaps. It might help solve you problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your code is doing what you think it is.

The Scan0 value of BitmapData gives the address of the first pixel in the bitmap. You then traverse the memory space for X bytes (BlockSize.Width * BlockSize.Height * BytesPerPixel) which is 100 x 100 x 32.

This does not give you a 100x100 block but just the first few scan lines. You need to do some arithmetic using the BitmapData.Stride property to calculate how many pixels are in a Scan Line. You only want the first 100xBytesPerPixel bytes from each Scan Line and then advance your memory pointer to skip until the beginning of the next Scan Line.

Comment: i updated the code.. is that what you mean to? i have to iterate through each line for comparing a block? :(
i'm not sure if the current code works fine... can you have a look please?

Comment: Yes that is the correct way to go about it. You must iterate each line. The bitmap data is not held in a 2D array, but in a series of Scan Lines (which may be longer that the Bit Depth multiplied by the Bitmap Width - so thats why we use Stride - this gives us the accurate memory footprint of a single line of the bitmap.

Comment: i'll have to do long work here...need to compare each block of my screen... for the **entire** screen. :(